# Problema con el ruteo multiple de angular 12. Mantiene la ultima ruta y no inicia desde la raiz a buscar

Tags: angular, angular-router

Estoy desarrollando mi aplicación en angular, por lo cual por cuestiones de mantenibilidad, coherencia y escalabilidad, quiero tener mis rutas separadas cada una en el modulo que corresponde:

- Security
- Order
- Etc

Para lograr tal motivo, me guie basándome en la [documentación de angular sobre ruteo](https://angular.io/guide/router-tutorial-toh) y [este video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Kb1_zuq0cI&list=PLUQOr3B0A7jUtlaX7djHnFGneqImT7qHi&index=13) (pero lo había deja de lado esa forma de navegar por este problema, que no se si al final es una mejor opción), quedando el ruteo inicial de mi aplicación de la siguiente manera:

**app.component.html**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**main-layout.component**

```
<app-header></app-header>

<app-sidenav> 
  <ng-container routerOutlet> 
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </ng-container>
</app-sidenav>
```

**app-routing.module**

```
  const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'order',
    loadChildren: () => import('@appRoot/modules/order/order.module').then(x => x.OrderModule)
  },

  // Otros modulos...

  { path: '',   redirectTo: 'notfound', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent }
];
```

**order-routing.module**

```
    const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: MainLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        children: [
          { path: 'tablelist', component: TableListComponent },
          { path: 'createtable', component: CreateTableComponent },

          { path: 'dineinlist', component: DineInListComponent }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

El problema que estoy teniendo es que inicialmente parece que el ruteo funciona. Si yo me ruteo con un `<a>` de la siguiente forma:

```
<a [routerLink]="['tablelist']">Mesas</a>
```

Me redirige a la URL `http://localhost:4200/tablelist` o a cualquiera de las `URL` colocadas a nivel del `sidenav`, pero, si dentro de este componente hago click en un botón de crear mesa para dirigirme a mi `CreateTableComponent`, la URL me dice que no encontró la pagina, mostrando esta `URL` en el depurador: `http://localhost:4200/createtable/userlist`. Y si a modo de prueba, coloco un `<a>` dentro de este componente para redirigirme a un componente de listado de usuarios, obtengo esta URL: `http://localhost:4200/tablelist/createtable/userlist`. ¿Por qué me hace esta concatenación de `URLs` si navego dentro de componentes, en lugar de iniciar de cero buscando la `URL` que coincida? (por ejemplo en lugar de `http://localhost:4200/tablelist/createtable` mas bien `http://localhost:4200/createtable` al navegar con `[routerLink]="['createtable']"`)

Comment: si quieres navegar a una ruta absoluta tienes que indicarlo con la `/`. Si no por defecto, te  cogerá como ruta padre la actual y le concatenará la que tenga el link. Si desde order module quieres ir a user module. Tienes que poner la ruta con la barra `/userlist`.

Comment: Era eso, me falto el entendimiento de es parte. ¿Lo podrías poner como respuesta (anexando alguna información extra si te parece muy corta) así la marco como tal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para navegar a un módulo que no está dentro de la ruta actual tienes que usar la ruta absoluta, es decir, indicarlo con la `/`.

Si no por defecto, te cogerá como ruta padre la actual y le concatenará la que tenga el link y angular intentará renderizar algún componente haciendo match con la ruta, de lo contrario mostrará el 404 (si está definido).

Por ejemplo, si desde `order.module` quieres ir a `user.module` tienes que poner la ruta con la barra `/userlist`.

[Navegación entre rutas](https://angular.io/guide/router#using-relative-paths)